# How make jquery loop over with number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to assign a number to my variable i.e. colorswap1, colorswap 2, colorswap 3

I have the following

```
var i = 1-36;

    // Get current image src
    var curSrc = $('#colorswap'[i]).attr('src');
```

It doesn't seem to be putting the desired: colorswap1, colorswap2

Answer (score 5):

Your variable declaration is doing the algebraic subtraction and will result in `-35`. You need a loop of some sort. Then, you concatenate the index with the string using the `+` operator. Because one of the things is a string, it will concatenate instead of "add".

Below is an example of what you can do:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 36; i++) {
    var curSrc = $('#colorswap' + i).attr('src');
    // now do stuff with curSrc here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response sach.  I tried adding it but the script is still stagnant:

Comment: @CamdenRoberts, you'll have to update your question with what you have right now so I can help further.